# Solve $e^{-x}=\ln(1/x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, systems-of-equations

Can someone help me solve this

$$e^{-x}=\ln(1/x)$$

I think these two functions are inverses of each other and since they both meet the line $y=x$ they intersect

But I'm not able to simplify the equality above to find their point of intersection

Help me, please.

Comment: Try using Lambert W function.

Comment: WolframAlpha solves it as $x = 0.56714329040978\dots$. The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.56714329040978&lookup_type=smart) gives this as $x = W(1)$ with the Lambert W function and $W(1)$ as the [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant).

Answer (score 1):

There is no analytical solution to this equation even using special functions. Then you will need some numerical method for finding the zero of function
$$f(x)=e^{-x}+\log(x)$$ Its derivative 
$$f'(x)=-e^{-x}+\frac 1x$$ cancels when $x=-W(-1)$ which is a complex number; so, $f'(x)>0 $and there is only one root.

By inspection, $f(1)=\frac 1e >0$. So, using Newton method with $x_0=1$ will give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.0000000000 \\
 1 & 0.4180232931 \\
 2 & 0.5413727558 \\
 3 & 0.5664266698 \\
 4 & 0.5671427445 \\
 5 & 0.5671432904
\end{array}
\right)$$

We could have generated a better estimate of the starting point building first the simplest Padé approximant at $x=1$
$$f(x) \simeq \frac{\frac{1}{e}+\frac{(2 e-1) }{2 e}(x-1)}{1+\frac{1}{2}(x-1)}$$ giving $x_0=\frac{2 e-3}{2 e-1}\approx 0.549201$.

Continuing with $[1,n]$  Padé approximants, it will be closer and closer to the solution as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 &  \frac{-3+2 e}{-1+2 e} &   0.5492006529 \\
 2 &  \frac{-8+34 e-36 e^2+12 e^3}{-2+16 e-24 e^2+12   e^3} & 0.5651368901 \\
 3 &  \frac{30-300 e+636 e^2-504 e^3+144 e^4}{6-108 e+348 e^2-360   e^3+144 e^4} & 0.5670287743 \\
 4 &  \frac{-144+3216 e-12480 e^2+18000 e^3-11520 e^4+2880   e^5}{-24+1056 e-5520 e^2+10800 e^3-8640 e^4+2880 e^5} &   0.5671134681
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @Lee. I am obviously wrong when I write *There is no analytical solution to this equation even using special functions*. As Robert Israel commented, the solution is the so-called $\Omega$ constant. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, the functions $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=\log(1/x)$ are inverses. If $f(x)$ intersects $y=x$ at $a$ then we have $f(a)=a$. Applying $g$ we get $a=g(a)$. Then $f(a)=g(a)$ and $a$ is a solution for the equation. So we have $a = f(a) = e^{-a}$, which is equivalent to $a e^a = 1$. This is precisely the equation that is solved by the Lambert $W$ function. Apply $W$ to get $a = W(1)$

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-x)%3Dlog(1%2Fx)) gives a numeric solution $x \approx 0.56714$  I don't think it surprising that it did not give an analytic result.  This looks like an equation that will not yield to algebra.

Comment: Mathway gave me $\approx{0.36787894412}$ which is $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, Maple doesn't solve it symbolically either.  But the solution is $W(1)$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: @Gnumbertester Probably you entered the wrong equation.  $1/e$ is certainly not a solution.

Comment: @RobertIsreal That's interesting. It's easy to see that it is not a solution but Mathway still gives it. Here is what I entered it in.<https://www.mathway.com/Calculus>